# Java BufferedReader check next lines of a loop before looping

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader

I'm parsing a .cvs file.
For each line of the cvs, I create an object with the parsed values, and put them into a set.

Before putting the object in the map and looping to the next, I need to check if the next cvs's line is the same object as the actual, but with a particular property value different.

For that, I need check the next lines of the buffer, but keep the loop's buffer in the same position.

For example:

```
BufferedReader input  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"ISO-8859-1"));
String line = null;

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    do something

    while ((nextline = input.readLine()) != null) { //now I have to check the next lines
       //I do something with the next lines. and then break.
    }
    do something else and continue the first loop.
}
```

Comment: `BufferedReader()` has `mark()` and `reset()` methods that may assist you (I have never used these so that is why I am not posting these as an answer).

Comment: Can simply call input.mark() without passing any parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can mark the current position using [`BufferedReader.mark(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29). To return to the position you call `BufferedReader.reset()`. The parameter to `mark` is the "read ahead limit"; if you try to `reset()` after reading more than the limit you may get an IOException.
2. Or you could use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead:

   ```
   // Get current position
   long pos = raf.getFilePointer();
   // read more lines...
   // Return to old position
   raf.seek(pos);
   ```
3. Or you could use [`PushbackReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushBackReader.html) which allows you to `unread` characters. But there's the drawback: `PushbackReader` does not provide a `readLine` method.

Comment: How can I use the input.mark() method? I mean. I need to pass a parameter (I guess it's the position I want to mark), but how do I retrieve it, since I'm reading lines?

Comment: It marks the current position. There is no way to retrieve it, you can only ask the stream to kindly go back to the position you marked earlier. The parameter determines how far you can read before the mark is invalidated. If you go further you may not be able to `reset()` the stream.

It has its limitations and you have to accept them, or use something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with nested do…while loops, without re-reading anything from your stream:

```
public void process(File file) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1"));
    String batchParent = input.readLine(); // read the first line in the file, this is a new batch
    String batchChild;
    do {
        currentBatch = new Batch(batchParent);
        do {
            batchChild = input.readLine();
        } while (addToBatchIfKeysMatch(batchParent, batchChild));
        // if we break out of the inner loop, that means batchChild is a new parent
        // assign it to batchParent and continue the outer loop
        batchParent = batchChild;
    } while (batchParent != null);
}

private boolean addToBatchIfKeysMatch(final String batchParent, final String batchChild) {
    if (batchChild != null && keysMatch(batchParent, batchChild)) {
        currentBatch.add(batchChild);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The key is to just read each file and either process it as a child line in the inner loop, or set the parentLine to the newly read value and continue the outer loop.